# I have a question about the Google Cloud Platform DataFusion product

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I wonder if data distribution function exists after ETL work in Google Cloud Platform datafusion.

If datafusion cannot provide data distribution method after ETL work, is there a way to provide distribution using another 3-party tool?

I wonder if data distribution is provided after ETL work in datafusion.

Comment: What is your aim with data distribution process after ETL?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your use case?